# Get latest ID in Django returns object is not iterable

Tags: django

I tried to get the latest id in Django but get the error.

```
def getlatestid(request):
    cot_info = COT.objects.latest('id')
    return JsonResponse({"data": list(cot_info)})

TypeError: 'COT' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`latest(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#latest) returns an object, not a list. So, you can try like this to fix the error:

```
def getlatestid(request):
    cot_info = COT.objects.values().latest('id')
    return JsonResponse({"data": cot_info})
```